# Google Street View https request is outputting link in html rather than sending request

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working on the neighborhood map and in my info window I want to have a small div that contains a street view of the stadium. I created a unique https request for each of the location and the only thing is that it is printing the actual link rather than making the request and displaying the google maps street view image. I will have the code in question below as well as a link to the github repository for the project

```
lInfowindow.setContent("<div><h2>" + currentMarker.content.name + "</h2><h3>" + currentMarker.content.address + "</h3><div>" + currentMarker.content.streetViewRequest + "</div></div>");
```

github repository: https://github.com/omar-jandali/neighborhood-map

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself, not a link to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

when you want to draw an image, you must use a `<img/>`

```
lInfowindow.setContent("<div><h2>" + currentMarker.content.name + "</h2><h3>" + 
                        currentMarker.content.address + "</h3><div> <img src='" + 
                        currentMarker.content.streetViewRequest + "'/> </div></div>");
```